# No matching function for call to & No member named

Tags: c++

I'm getting two errors.

First error about "output.add (R1.voltage());" line.It gives "No member named 'add'in'std::__1::array"

Second error about calling function.It gives " No matching function for call to '   ' "

Here is my header;

```
static array<double,1> diodeClipper (array<double,1> input, double Fs){

// 1 ohm is the Ri voltage source resistor
double Ri = 1.0;

// Internal circuit parameters
VoltageSource Vin (0.0, Ri); // initialize voltage at 0V
Resistor R1 (80.0);
Capacitor C1 (3.5e-5, Fs); // Capacitor & Inductor need sampling rate (Fs) in constructor

// create WDF circuit
Serie RC (&R1, &C1);
Serie root (&Vin, &RC);

// accurate simulation of GZ34 valve diode.
double Is = 125.56; // reverse saturation current
double Vt = 0.036;  // thermal voltage

// initial value for the voltage over the diode (n-1 memory)
double Vdiode = 0.0;

// for simulation
double b, r, Rdiode;
array<double,1> output;



// the simulation loop
int n=0; int max=input.size();
for (; n<max; ++n)
{
    Vin.Vs = input[n];                  // read the input signal for the voltage source
    b = root.reflected ();              // get the waves up to the root
    // ** VALVE RESISTOR **
    Rdiode = Is * exp(-Vt * Vdiode);    // the nonlinear resistance of the diode
    r = (Rdiode - root.R)               // update scattering coefficient (KCL)
    / (Rdiode + root.R);
    root.incident (r * b);              // evaluate the wave leaving the diode (root element)
    // ** UPDATE **
    Vdiode = root.voltage ();           // update the diode voltage for next time sample
    output.add (R1.voltage());          // the output is the voltage over the resistor R1

}
return output;}
```

And my main.cpp

```
*out1 = diodeClipper(*in1, Fs); //Where i get "No matching..." error
*out2 = diodeClipper(*in2, Fs); //Where i get "No matching..." error
```

Comment: add the code directly not links

Comment: Post code, not screenshots. Paste your code, then select it and press ctrl+K to format it as code.

Comment: `double` ≠ `array<double, 1>`.

Comment: Sorry,i just added codes.

Comment: When you edited your question, you did not include the declarations of `in1` and `out`, as included in your screenshot, and that context is vital to answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

"No member named 'add'in'std::__1::array": `std::array` does not support the `add` function. The correct push function for the standard C++ containers is `push_back` and even then, `std::array` does not support it because its size is fixed at compile time.

No matching function for call: `diodeClipper` takes an `std::array` as an argument, but you are passing it a double (dereferencing a C-style array). `std::array` is a template class and is totally different from C-style arrays.

Comment: My friend told me that use std::vector instead of array.I tried but still getting errors...

Comment: @RıdvanKüçük Did you replace `add` with `push_back`?

Comment: Oh,sorry.Yes i changed but getting still same error.push_back worked but still no function to call...

Comment: In your question, you said that you got two errors. Was one of the errors fixed? Remember that you need to pass a std::vector to your function, not a double or a C-array.

Comment: Yes.First one fixed.Thanks for that.Used std::vector instead of std::array and used push_back.But still no matching function error...

Comment: Ok, good. For your second error, what types are `in1`, `in2`, `out1`, and `out2`? In your original code, they are C-style arrays and you dereferenced them to pass them, passing the function a double. You should make `in1`, `in2`, `out1`, and `out2` `std::vector`s and pass them without using the `*` (dereferencing them).

Comment: They are double.How should i make them vector?

Comment: @RıdvanKüçük Their types should be `std::vector<double>` and you should pass them to the function without the asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for tip.But i'm getting "no viable conversion from 'double *' to 'std::vector<double>" error if i do that.

Comment: How did you create the vector? You need to do `std::vector<double> in1 {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`, but replacing those numbers with whatever numbers you are using.

Comment: std::vector<double> in1 {0};
  std::vector<double> in2 {1};
  std::vector<double> out1 {0};
  std::vector<double> out2 {1};

I did like this.Now i can compile with "expression result unused" warning.

Comment: But program not working.Can't get result as compiler said.

Comment: @RıdvanKüçük Sorry, I can't help you with that. I don't have the full context and you'll need to learn how to debug by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i understand everything.The problem is about framework which i use.I asked framework's forum.It's easy but i can't figure it out.Thanks!